# jquery metismenu not working loading data async with AngularJS controller

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have a problem with Jquerymetis menu. I want to load menu elements from Database and I'm using AngujarJS controller to get the JSON with menu elements.

Here is AngularJSController

```
var appControllers = angular.module('appControllers', []);

appControllers.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
      var url = "/api/Menus/GetMenuElements";
      $http.post(url).
        success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            $scope.menuElements = data;
            console.log("Success");
        }).
        error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
            console.log("Error");
        });
  }]);
```

Then in a PartialView of my ASP.NET MVC project I have the Angular directives to add the elements to menu.

```
<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
    <li ng-repeat="elementL1 in menuElements" ng-init="menuElements != null">
        <a ng-if="elementL1.LINK !== null" href="{{elementL1.LINK}}"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span class="nav-label">{{elementL1.NAME}}</span><span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
        <a ng-if="elementL1.LINK == null"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> <span class="nav-label">{{elementL1.NAME}}</span> </a>

        <ul ng-repeat="elementL2 in elementL1.ChildMenu" ng-if="elementL1.ChildMenu.length > 0" class="nav nav-second-level">
            <li class="primerLi">
                <a>{{elementL2.NAME}}<span class="fa arrow"></span></a>
                <ul ng-if="elementL2.ChildMenu.length > 0" class="nav nav-third-level">
                    <li ng-repeat="elementL3 in elementL2.ChildMenu">
                        <a href="{{elementL3.LINK}}">{{elementL3.NAME}}</a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

This is adding fine the elements to the menu but it doesn't work the collapse and expand. It apear expanded and I can't collapse the elements.

I think that the problem is that I have to call `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` after loading elements but if i call this on the browser console it doesn't work.

How can achieve this? I'm new with Angular. Here I have seen the same issue but I could't solve the problem.
https://github.com/onokumus/metisMenu/issues/22

**EDIT**

I have discovered that the Metis Menu could not be called more than once. I have deleted `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` from the onready event JS and I called it from Browser console and it now works.

Now I need help to call it using angular when the menu elements are loaded. I'm new at Angular and I need some help.

Comment: I have edited my question adding some conclusion about the problem.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have solved the problem using an Angular Directive to execute the metisMenu function when last element of the ng-repeat is rendered to the DOM.

```
app.directive('metis', function ($timeout) {
    return function ($scope, $element, $attrs) {
        if ($scope.$last == true) {
            $timeout(function () {
                $('#side-menu').metisMenu();
            }, 250)
        }
    };
});
```

Then I have to use the directive on the Ng repeat element

```
<li ng-repeat="elementL1 in menuElements" ng-init="menuElements != null" metis="">
```

You can see the complete HTML code on my question.

I'm totally new to Angular so I'm not an expert. Even that I hope this solution can help someone.

Answer (score 1):

[MetisMenu](https://github.com/onokumus/metismenu/) could not be called more than once because it calls `init()` function only once in its lifetime.

So it means if you are loading content of a element `<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">` asynchronously using ajax and after that again binding event to `<ul class="nav" id="side-menu">` by `$('#side-menu').metisMenu();` won't make any difference.

So what you have to do is firstly destroy the existing metismenu event handler and then create a new one like below:

```
$('#side-menu').metisMenu('dispose'); //For stop and destroy metisMenu
$('#side-menu').metisMenu();
```

So your **AngularJS Controller** should be like below:

```
var app = angular.module('app', []);

app.controller('MenuCtrl', ['$scope', '$http',
  function ($scope, $http) {
    var url = "/api/Menus/GetMenuElements";
    $http.post(url)
      .success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        angular.element("#side-menu").metisMenu('dispose');  //Destroy the existing metisMenu
        $scope.menuElements = data;
        angular.element("#side-menu").metisMenu(); //Create new binding
        console.log("Success");
      })
      .error(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        console.log("Error");
      });
  }
]);
```