# metisMenu defaults to all open when used with Angular

Tags: jquery, angularjs

I'm converting an existing site that's based on the [SB Admin 2](http://startbootstrap.com/template-overviews/sb-admin-2/) template to using Angular.  SB Admin 2 uses the metisMenu jquery plugin.  I ran into a problem at first using ng-repeat to generate my menu items where it seemed that metisMenu was not being activated.  I solved that by following the S.O. solution posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34026478/jquery-metismenu-not-working-loading-data-async-with-angularjs-controller) by creating a custom directive that activates metisMenu after ng-repeat is finished.

However, my problem now is that all my menu items parents and subchildren all default to expanded when the page loads instead of defaulting to collapsed.  If I click to close one of the items, they all shrink down and behavior returns to normal.

Here is my html (note, I had to change the default angular delimiters: {{ }} to <{ }> because I am using Django):

```
// data.files is some json data I load via ajax in my controller
<div ng-controller="sidebarCtrl" class="navbar-default sidebar" id="sidebar" role="navigation">
  <div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li ng-repeat="item in data.files" metis="">
        <a href="#"><{ item.pretty_name }></a>
        <ul class="nav nav-second-level">
          <li>
              <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
          </li>
          <li>
              <a href="#">Second Level Item</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

And here is what it looks like on initial load with everything expanded:

[image]

How do I get my sidebar menu to default to all closed when the page loads using SB Admin 2 and metisMenu with Angular?  If I don't use ng-repeat and just generate the menu items manually, they work as expected.  It's only after using ng-repeat to generate the list items that they default to all expanded.